# Mysql Event scheduler on Linux

Tags: mysql, events

I have tried in my `/etc/my.cnf` file:

```
event-scheduler = ON
```

using MYSQL 5.5.
I have turned service off/on, but no global variable `EVENT_SCHEDULER = ON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `[mysqld]` section of the `my.cnf`, add this:

```
event_scheduler=ON
```

That should enable it for future start ups.

For your current MySQL session you can enable it by doing this:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```